# How to restore package Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

My computer got corrupted and I needed to re install the OS. After installing Visual Studio 2017, I tried to open my project, but I didn't find any packages. I tried to install each one of them with Nuget, but it didn't work because every time I try to install a package, I got a lot of errors about other missing package.

What can I do to make it work again? I am really running out of time here...

Comment: Have you tried `Update-Package -reinstall` ? Which should update/reinstall all packages in the solution

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it by running  **dotnet restore** in the cmd.exe with the path of the project this link was useful for me  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore